# What's the difference betwwen fileChannel.force() and mappedByteBuffer.force()

Tags: java, rabbitmq

[image]

What's the difference betwwen `fileChannel.force()` and `mappedByteBuffer.force()`?

I think `MappedByteBuffer` is mapped by `FileChannel`. So `fileChannel.force()` is sufficient. Why `RocketMQ` uses 2 ways to flush data to disk.

```
MappedByteBuffer buf = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, 1024);
```